# how can i make a HTML submit button which hand you/generate a PDF?

Tags: html, pdf

Example provided would be helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better for StackOverflow?

Comment: yes! Goto Stackoverflow and write a more detailed question!! Generating a PDF with a HTML submit button? With what programming language?? .... -1

Comment: In java. Det idea was to get the PDF button in google wave

Answer (score 2):

use iText. its a great library. you have to hack a lot together if your pdf grows, but overall very handy

http://itextpdf.com/

basic document creation:

```
Document document = new Document();
try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(
    new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

While this will probably get migrated, your best bet would be implementing something like [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html).